# How do I specify database in odoo Controller

Tags: odoo-14

How do I specify database in odoo Controller rather than select it manually from the browser?

My code

```
@http.route('/test/', type='http', auth='public', website=True, db='test')
    def index(self, **kw):
        return "Salutation"
```

this is what I did and then if I went to localhost:8069/test/ I got 404 Not found error.
but if I go to localhost:8069/database/selector and select the database I get the right response.
How do I specify the database in odoo Controller rather than select it manually from the browser

Comment: You need to add dbfilter to odoo server run command or in your conf file. and your controller will work.

Answer (score 0):

On your server, in src/odoo, you should create a new file:
my_odoo_configuration.conf, where you can store the information about the main database you are using:

```
[options]
addons_path = ...
...
db_name = my_database_2
```

And you can switch the database when launching odoo from the command line:

```
/src/odoo/odoo-bin -c my_odoo_configuration.conf -d my_database_1 ...
```

More configuration details can be found on the official documentation:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/cli.html#database